# Caching datastore query

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I'm not familiar with node programming, so I'm sure the error here is around syntax.

I'm trying to query datastore and store the returned entity as a const config reference in my function.

For some reason, if I invoke this as part of the body of the function I always get undefined instead of the value. Moving the invocation to the function that is called works, but I need the values to configure the function so it can't be on the first invocation.

Any ideas?

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
const datastore = Datastore();
const query = datastore
  .createQuery('ProxyConfig')
  .filter('function', '=', 'proxy');

const proxyConfig = loadConfig();

function loadConfig() {
    datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
    console.log("Query executed");  
    console.log(results);
    return results; 
});

}


exports.proxy = (req, res) => {
  cnf = loadConfig();
  console.log(`config is ${cnf}`);
  res.status(200).send(cnf);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from the function **loadConfig** which is why you're seeing `undefined`.  With promises like that you want to return the promise and then get the results.  By using `.then` and returning an item within that function the value will be wrapped inside another promise.  So you can write this in two different ways.  I'll first use the code above as is:

```
function loadConfig() {
  return datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
    console.log("Query executed");  
    console.log(results);
    return results; 
});

}

exports.proxy = (req, res) => {
  const configPromise = loadConfig().then(results => {
    const cnf = results;
    console.log(`config is ${cnf}`);
    res.status(200).send(cnf);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
};
```

However, since you are simply forwarding the results of the promise to the calling function this code can be simplified to:

```
exports.proxy = (req, res) => {
  datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
    const cnf = results;
    console.log(`config is ${cnf}`);
    res.status(200).send(cnf);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you, so since I need that to be outside of the function, I want to avoid that datastore query to be called every invocation. I guess the node way of doing is to assign all my variables inside the then clause of the promise, and those would then be available for the function being executed right?

Comment: Is there another route to go besides storing the config in datastore?  Can you just deploy a json file with the function and load that during the initialization of the function?  Think about the first time the function is called, it is going to call the code outside of that function one time which is when you could synchronously load the config file, it's a small hit in time.  After that you're guaranteed to have the configuration for every function invocation.